# Doctrine 2 hydrate multiple related objects

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two entities - Banner and Category. There is M:N relationship between them.

I would like to get banners which are in specified categories. But I need to get some data from categories also (I need level, because I will sort Banners depending on category level).

I'm using query builder:

```
            $queryBuilder->from('App\Model\Entities\Banner','b')
            ->select('b', 'cat')
            ->join('b.categories', 'cat')
            ->where('cat.id IN (:categories)')
            ->orderBy('cat.level', 'DESC')
            ->setParameter('categories', $categoryIds);
```

Neither hydratation method I use, I always get only one entity - Banner. I think it is because Banner has relation to category, so Doctrine is not hydrating entity Category.

Update: If I use `SCALAR` hydratation mode, I'm getting data from both entities. But working with it is painful :(

I tried adding select `NEW` operator and creating new object, but in that case I didn't get Banner, I was getting only new object BannerDTO.

`$queryBuilder->addSelect('NEW App\Model\BannerDTO(cat.level, b.id)')`

I also tried some experiments with `PARTIAL` queries and so on, but it wasn't successful either :(

Is it possible to get entity and its related entities? I'm expecting array with 2 entities in it - Banner and Category. Doctrine is getting all the necessary data from database in one SQL query anyway.

Comment: Did you try `leftJoin()`?

Comment: What does your relationship look like? Maybe you have the owning/reverse side swapped?